# Ember.js add class to action helper template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I specify a class to an item when clicked with Ember. I am using a Handlebars action on the  elements of a table to sort by properties. I want to add a class to the property being sorted so I can show the user the current property being sorted. How can I do this?

I have an ember controller shown below:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  title: 'Users'
  count: Ember.computed.alias 'length'
  sortProperties: ['username']
  actions:
    sort: (property) ->
      console.log property
      if @get('sortProperties')[0] is property
        @set('sortAscending', !@get 'sortAscending')
      else
        @set 'sortProperties', [property]
        @set('sortAscending', true)
```

The controller allows me to click on headings in a table to sort the table. The html is shown below:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Action</th>
    <th class="sort" {{action sort 'last'}}>Last</th>
    <th class="sort" {{action sort 'first'}}>First</th>
    <th class="sort" {{action sort 'username'}}>Username</th>
    <th class="sort" {{action sort 'email'}}>Email</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a `currentSort` property (optional)

First, I created a `currentSort` property on your `App.UsersController` which cleans a little bit the code. We'll use it later.

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  sortProperties: ['username']
  currentSortBinding: 'sortProperties.firstObject'

  actions:
    sort: (sort) ->
      if sort is @get('currentSort')
        @toggleProperty 'sortAscending'
      else
        @setProperties
          currentSort: sort
          sortAscending: true
```

### Define a custom view for each `<th>`

You'll then have [to define a custom view](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/defining-a-view/) for the `<th>` which will do 2 things:

- Have a class `active-sort` when the sort of the view is the current
- Change the controllers current sort when `click`ing the view

It will looks like this:

```
App.SortView = Ember.View.extend
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.sortName}}')
  tagName: 'th'
  sortName: null # (will be different for each <th> : `last`, `first`,..)

  classNameBindings: [ ':sort', 'isCurrent:active-sort' ]

  isCurrent: (->
    @get('sortName') is @get('controller.currentSort')
  ).property('sortName', 'controller.currentSort')

  click: ->
    var newSort = @get('sortName');
    @get('controller').send('sort', newSort);
```

Here we [customized the view class names](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/customizing-a-views-element/), and we [handled `click` event on the view](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/).

### Insert a custom view for each sort

This is really simple to [insert views in templates](http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/):

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {{view App.SortView sortName="default"}}
    {{view App.SortView sortName="price"}}
    {{view App.SortView sortName="alphabetical"}}
  </tr>
</thead>
```

You can test all of this [in a working JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yezuxevaquji/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This is perfect. I was looking into the custom view method but mine was using jQuery. This works even better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best workaround, but you could have some "sort flag" that you could bind CSS on.

In your controller (in "classic" javascript) :

```
sortedByLast : function() { return this.get("sortProperties")[0] === "last" }.property("sortProperties.@each")
// etc ...
```

In your template :

```
<th {{bind-attr class=":sort sortedByLast:current-sort"}} {{action sort 'last'}}>Last</th>
```

So the `sort` class would always be on, and the `current-sort` would only be there if it match its proper flag.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar but I wanted something a little more automatic so I don't have to created sort functions for every property. Right now I have a view template for the <th> tags and it uses jQuery to set the classes. I don't know if it's the best method either but it is working.